# Update props value to build seeker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I´m trying to create a seeker with vuejs 3 using composition API and laravel 10.

I need update a dynamically table when search register by name for example. My table it´s filled from other component (form). All my registers i can show it ok, but if i need search one
specifically i have input text to do this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control name_search" placeholder="Name" @keyup="searchName('name')">
```

In my function i have:

```
<script setup>

const searchName = (action) => {
        let value = document.getElementsByClassName('searchName')[0].value
        const params = [action, value];
        
        queryForKeywords(params)
    }

const queryForKeywords = async (event) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/listingApi/show?page=${1}`, { params: { 'searchParams': event } }) 
        //emit('update:valor', await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)));
        props.valor.value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    };
```

In my script i have `props` `valor` that i´m using to fill my table. I think that i can use this prop to change value in my seeker but not change.

My data i can show it in network tab, this it´s a example:

```
{"data":[{"id":15624,"name":"Cobo Gonzalez
```

My definition props:

```
const props = defineProps({
        valor: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
 .............
```

And in my template:

```
<template v-for="item in valor" :key="item.id">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="item.id" class="assign_register" name="assign_register" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"></td>
                        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.name }} </td>
                        <td>{{ item.address }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.province }} </td>
                        <td>{{ item.phone }} </td>
                        
                        <td>
                   ........................
```

I tryed use `watch` and `watchEffect` but same result, maybe i don´t know how use it...

```
const search = watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
      
        return props.valor.value;
      
    });
```

how i sayed my table it´s filled ok from my form, not when i seach one register. I need reload it when i search one register and update this table in execution time.

I tryed create a personaliced event, but i have same result i can´t update my table...

Thanks for readme, help me and sorry for my bad english